# Improve dynamic creation of array

Tags: javascript

I need to create an array of `strings` from `0.05` up to `12`, increasing of `0.05`.

To do so I'm doing this:

```
function createDuration(){
    var n = 0.05;
    var arr = [String(n)];
    while(n < 12){ 
        n += 0.05;
        var temp = n.toFixed(2); 
        arr.push(String(temp));
    };
    return arr;
}
```

This is, however, pretty slow. would you have any suggestion to improve it? I would be able to use `_` if it would help, but not `jQuery`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Number#toFixed()` returns already a string

```js
function createDuration() {
    var n = 0.05,
        arr = [];
    while (n < 12.05) {
        arr.push(n.toFixed(2));
        n += 0.05;
    };
    return arr;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(createDuration(), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Or with fixed values:

```js
function createDuration() {
    return Array.apply(null, { length: 240 }).map(function (_, i) {
        return ((i + 1) / 20).toFixed(2);
    });
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(createDuration(), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: You mean [`Number.prototype.toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed), surely?

Comment: In your first solution last value is "11.95", but it must be "12.00"

Comment: 12.000000000000014 > 12